# Force table columns to be fixed after contents load

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table in which I do sorting and filtering, and when I do filtering the width of my columns vary. I want to know if there is a way to force the table to keep its width after the contents load into my table. So that when I do filtering or sorting nothing would move and it will just keep its width in every column.

I need to keep the width static AFTER data loads into the table because I don't always load the same data. I first want the data to adjust nicely into the table and then never let it change width after my sorting or filtering.

Thanks.

Comment: You could get the actual width of your columns in px with `clientWidth` after they are loaded and then set the `width` to that value.

Comment: Can you add the HTML/CSS code of the table to the question?

Comment: Can't do that, some other data coming in might have a different width, I don't load the same data every time. On page load I want my table to adjust but after data loads into my table I want the width to stay static and never change.

Comment: Ram Tobolski, no I can't, because I'm working with JSF lol. It will get a little to complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your problem correctly. You could leave your cell `width` on `auto` as long as the data loads so your table adjusts the way you want. Then when the data is filtered, read the actual width of the columns in px

```
var firstColumnWidth = $("td:nth-child(1)").get(0).clientWidth;
```

and set `width` to that fixed value

```
$("td:nth-child(1)").each(function(i){$(this).css("width",firstColumnWidth+"px");});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3vqja4sa/

Comment: This is not sufficient. Changes in cell content may cause changes in column width allocation, unless you set (in the script executed after initial page load) `table-layout: fixed` and set the `width` property of the table to a specific value (the sum of the column widths).

Comment: As I understand the question the content of the cells does not change after the initial loading of data. But good point if it does.

Answer (score 0):

add style to your table, that will fix your issue

```
#table-id{
 position:fixed;
 display:block;
}
```

or

```
  #table-id{
  position:fixed;
  display:inline-block;
  }
```

Comment: What I really need is for my width to stay static AFTER I load data into it. For page load I want my table to adjust to the data coming in, but after that I want the width of the columns to remain static and never change.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the each column some min or max width.

```
.custom-max
{
max-width: value; 
}
```

OR

```
.custom-min
{
min-width: value;
}
```

Comment: What I really need is for my width to stay static AFTER I load data into it. For page load I want my table to adjust to the data coming in, but after that I want the width of the columns to remain static and never change.